# How can I use p5js with Angular effectively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, p5.js

So I installed p5 via npm and imported it into a component. It was working great until I was going to build the project and realized that angular compiled the entire p5js into main.js and that the site was now 1.9 MB.

Obviously, I would like the project to be smaller. Is there any way to use p5js with angular without installing the whole library?

In my project I am creating a p5 canvas in multiple components.

Answer (score 2):

So many ways are not available to handle this. All files will compiled and bundled in the main.js.

But what you can do is to create a custom Module which import the `p5.js` lib and then you can use **lazy loading**.

Normally you do this in the `Router` like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then((m) => m.LazyModule),
      },
    ]),
```

But what you can do, too, is to handle it in a custom service like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LazyLoaderService {
  private lazyMap: Map<string, Promise<unknown>> = new Map()
  constructor() {}
  getLazyModule(key: string): Promise<unknown> {
    return this.lazyMap.get(key)
  }
  loadLazyModules(): Observable<number | void> {
    return of(1).pipe(
      delay(2000),
      tap(() => {
        this.lazyMap.set(
          'lazy',
          import('./lazy/lazy.module').then((m) => m.LazyModule)
        )
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Then Angular will split the modules and loading it if needed. But if you use it inside the App.Component.ts directly it will help you not so much, because the lazy module will be loaded directly on init.

Comment: But this will not decrease the size of the app?

Comment: No. It will load it lazy and the first part is 500kb instead if 1,5mb (as example!). But the complete app size do not change.